# XAMARIN.android - get id item menu

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

i'm new on xamarin, actually i'm working on android menu, but i have some problem to get the item ID and start activity for each item:

**MainActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "sofis3", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/Theme.DesignDemo")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;  
        NavigationView navigationView;  

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            var toolbar = FindViewById<V7Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Mipmap.ic_menu);
            drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);

        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)   
        {  
            Intent intent = null;

            //Console.WriteLine("ID = " + item.ItemId);

            switch (item.ItemId)   
            {  
                case Android.Resource.Id.Home:  
                    drawerLayout.OpenDrawer(Android.Support.V4.View.GravityCompat.Start);  
                    break;

                case Android.Resource.chi_siamo :
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ChiSiamoActivity));
                    break;

                case Android.Resource.Id.nostro_centro:
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(NostroCentroActivity));
                    break;

                case Android.Resource.Id.servizi_paziente:
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ServiziPazienteActivity));
                    break;

                case Android.Resource.Id.my_sofis:
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MySofisActivity));
                    break;

                case Android.Resource.Id.contatti:
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ContattiActivity));
                    break;

                case Android.Resource.Id.lavora_con_noi:
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LavoraConNoiActivity));
                    break;

                default://invalid option
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
            } 

            if (intent != null)
            {
                StartActivity(intent);
            }

            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);  
        }
```

I have two main layouts:

**Layout/Main.axml**
**Layout/menu/menu.xml**

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<menu  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">  
        <item  
            android:id="@+id/chi_siamo"  
            android:title="CHI SIAMO"
         />  
        <item  
            android:id="@+id/nostro_centro"  
            android:title="Il NOSTRO CENTRO" />  
        <item  
            android:id="@+id/servizi_paziente"  
            android:title="SERVIZI PER IL PAZIENTE" />  

        <item  
            android:id="@+id/my_sofis"  
            android:title="MY SOFIS" /> 

        <item  
            android:id="@+id/contatti"  
            android:title="CONTATTI" /> 

        <item  
            android:id="@+id/lavora_con_noi"  
            android:title="LAVORA CON NOI" /> 
    </group>  
</menu>
```

The issue is that "case Android.Resource.chi_siamo" doesn't get the ID so i can not start specific activity.

How can i get ID name and validate it ? 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all your `menu.xml` file should be in the following directory:

```
Resources -> menu -> menu.xml
```

**not** inside `Resources -> layout` .

Create the menu:

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu, menu);
    return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and then remove `Android` and add `Id` to line:

```
case Android.Resource.chi_siamo :
```

like:

```
case Resource.Id.chi_siamo :
```

Remove `Android` from all the other `switch` cases as well.